# Multiple lines in the header of a Beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, header-footer, multline

I found a template that I like. It is a template ready from [Radboud University Nijmegen](https://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Epim/beamer.php).

[image]

The name of the institution is bigger that *Radboud University Nijmegen*, So I would like to arrange the institution in two lines, how can I do this?

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=.9\@tempdimb]{logo}{ru_logo}%
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute~~}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
```

Thank you in advance for any your helpful tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this question. Just write

```
\vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute[width={4.5cm},center,respectlinebreaks]}\vfil}
```

`width` is the size of the line break.